# Why does split not return anything?

Tags: perl, split

I am trying to get that Perl `split` working for more than 2 hours. I don't see an error. Maybe some other eyes can look at it and see the issue. I am sure its a silly one:

```
@versionsplit=split('.',"15.0.3");

print $versionsplit[0];
print $versionsplit[1];
print $versionsplit[2];
```

I just get an empty array. Any idea why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need:

```
@versionsplit=split(/\./,"15.0.3");
```

The first argument to `split` is a regular expression, not a string. And `.` is the regex symbol which means ‘match any character’. So all the characters in your input string were being treated as separators, and `split` wasn't finding anything between them to return.

Answer (score 1):

the "`.`" represents any character.You need to escape it for split function to recognise as a field separator.
change your line to

```
@versionsplit=split('\.',"15.0.3");
```

Comment: I find that putting the first argument to `split` in a match operator (`//`) reinforces the fact that it's interpreted as a regex.